# how to select max score from duplicate mobile_number

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

how can I filter record 60122839991 with the highest score 95.3758 and return as below without duplicate phone number

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (mobile_number) t.*
from mytable t
order by mobile_number, score desc
```